# How can I sort an array of dictionaries by its key?

Tags: javascript, sorting

```
var arr = [ 
    { 'name': 'ashley', 'score': 5 },
    { 'name': 'jason', 'score': 9 },
    { 'name': 'ben', 'score': 1 },
    { 'name': 'jordan', 'score': 4 },
]
```

How can I reorder this array so that the results are score descending?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1129216/4175944

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like this:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    return b.score - a.score
});
```

This gives:

```
[
    {"name":"jason","score":9},
    {"name":"ashley","score":5},
    {"name":"jordan","score":4},
    {"name":"ben","score":1}
]
```